# How to make a program which "translates" letters?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I am trying to make a program, which replaces letters with other letters, for instance 'Q' into 'R', or 'D' into 'U'. I'm stuck here:

```
def dna():
    seq = input('Enter the sequence:')
    list1 = list(seq)
    for i in seq:
       if i == 'A':
           seq[i] = 'T'
    return ''.join(list1)
```

This returns an error. What can I do?

Comment: Look into the built-in function [`str.translate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate).

Comment: What is the bioinformatic transformation you want? Is this transcribing, reverse complementing, or translating sequences, or something else? Whatever it is, biopython can do this for you https://biopython.org/ Without more details you won't get a clear ansewr

Comment: @Chris_Rands I just want to make a simple code which transforms A(Adenin) into T(Thymin), G(Guanin) into C(Cytosin) and vice versa. I am a newbie in both biology and python and this doesn't have a particular purpose.

Comment: @coldspeed, that's not really an appropriate dupe IMO, there is a specific bioinformatics solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just want to make a simple code which transforms A(Adenin) into
>   T(Thymin), G(Guanin) into C(Cytosin) and vice versa.

Based on this clarification what you actually want to do is complement your DNA sequences. [Biopython](https://biopython.org/) provides this functionality:

```
>>> from Bio.Seq import Seq
>>> seq = Seq('ATCGGAT')
>>> seq.complement()
Seq('TAGCCTA', Alphabet())
```

You could build your own implementation if you needed, the biopython one uses `str.translate` in an alphabet aware way (to check your not mixing DNA/RNA etc.), see the [source code](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/Seq.py#L859).

Answer (score 1):

You have many answers to your problem but none address your issue, so looking at your code and hopefully this can help:

`seq` is a string and as such is immutable in python, so:

```
seq[i] = 'T'
```

is not valid python. You already created a `list1` so did you mean:

```
list1[i] = 'T'
```

Note, this still wouldn't work because `i` is not the index but a character in `seq` but you can get both the index and character with `enumerate()`, e.g.:

```
for i, c in enumerate(seq):
    if c == 'A':
        list1[i] = 'T'
...
```

In python `str.translate()` is ideal for translating multiple characters, e.g. for your simple example:

```
def dna():
    t = str.maketrans('A', 'T')
    seq = input('Enter the sequence: ')
    return seq.translate(t)
```

And this is easy to extend, e.g. `A->T` and `G->C` and vice versa would look like:

```
    t = str.maketrans('AGTC', 'TCAG')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's as easy as translating one character into another you can use replace. Is this what you want?

```
def dna():
    seq = input('Enter the sequence: ')
    return seq.replace('A', 'T')

print(dna())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str.**replace**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20replace#str.replace):

```
def dna(seq):
  # Replace Q with R
  seq = seq.replace("Q", "R")
  # Replace D with U
  seq = seq.replace("D", "U")
  return seq

seq = input('Enter the sequence:')
print(dna(seq))
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the sequence: QQQDDD
RRRUUU
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using a comprehension and a lookup dictionary, which should be more easily expandable to include more characters:

```
mapping = {'Q': 'R', 'D': 'U'}
seq = input('Enter the sequence:')
new = ''.join(mapping.get(c, c) for c in seq)
```

Example input 'QUAD' becomes 'RUAU'.

Answer (score 0):

```
def dna():
    d={'Adenin':'Thymin','Thymin':'Adenin','Guanin':'Cytosin','Cytosin':'Guanin'}
    seq = raw_input('Enter the sequence:')
    return d[seq]
print dna()
```

In simple terms, you can try making a dictionary and try to transforms A(Adenin) into T(Thymin), G(Guanin) into C(Cytosin) and vice versa.